# Get a list of first rows in each group

Tags: mysql, sql, for-loop, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

MySQL version 5.7, ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled

For each result `event_id IN (4610, 4609, 4608, 4607, 4606, 4605, 4604, 4603, 4602, 4601)`, it is necessary to calculate `LIMIT 1` (or `MIN(id)`), get the value `id` for the calculated string. As a result of the entire request, we get a list of `id`, from which we get a list of `image`. P.S. The value of `image` is very large, so you cannot interact directly.
Here is a working query, but it is very slow to execute! I need to write it differently, I don't understand how.

```
SELECT id, event_id, image
FROM eventImages
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM eventImages WHERE event_id IN (4610, 4609, 4608, 4607, 4606, 4605, 4604, 4603, 4602, 4601)
    GROUP BY event_id
)
ORDER BY event_id DESC;
```

```
create table eventImages
(
id int auto_increment
primary key,
uuid varchar(36) null,
event_id int null,
image mediumtext null
);
```

Comment: Replace WHERE IN with INNER JOIN. Ensure that the index by `(event_id, id)` exists.

Comment: You want "groupwise max".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7 you should use an `INNER JOIN` in place of the `WHERE ... IN` clause, as already suggested by @Akina in the comments section. This will make an improvement because the `WHERE ... IN` is not able to exploit indices (make sure to use and index on the "*eventImages.id*" field).

```
SELECT id, event_id, image
FROM       eventImages
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) AS id
            FROM eventImages 
            WHERE event_id BETWEEN 4601 AND 4610
            GROUP BY event_id) subquery
        ON eventImages.id = subquery.id 
ORDER BY event_id DESC;
```

Another option is to generate a ranking value using a variable. Then we can make a boolean value (0/1) that is triggered to 1 only when a change of the event_id is observed (so that we take only first id for each "*event_id*" value).

```
SET @curr_event_id = '';

SELECT event_id, id, image
FROM (SELECT IF(event_id <> @curr_event_id, 1, 0) AS rn,
             IF(event_id <> @curr_event_id, 
                @curr_event_id := event_id, 
                event_id                        ) AS event_id,
             id, 
             image
      FROM tab
      ORDER BY event_id, id) subquery
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

In MySQL 8.0 instead of self joining your table, try using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function and apply filtering as follows:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY id) AS rn 
    FROM eventImages 
    WHERE event_id BETWEEN 4601 AND 4610
)
SELECT id, event_id, image
FROM eventImages
WHERE rn = 1
```

It will assign 1 to the lowest "*id*" for each "*event_id*", then you can filter out your interesting rows.

Comment: Sorry, but I have MySQL version 5.7, and ROW_NUMBER appeared only with MySQL version 8. And also I have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY installed and I can't change it. I have now added this clarification to my question.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much! This is a very fast query!